# simple function doesn't work outside of for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

This simple function doesn't work because setup_color knows nothing about #L +i

Is there any easy fix ?

```
function setup_color() {
  $("#L" + i).css('background-color', "#DCC9FF");
}

for (let i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
  $temp = splitString[i];
  if ($temp > "") {
    $("#I" + i).val($temp);
    setup_color();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass the `i` as a param to the `setup_color` function

```
function setup_color(i){
    $("#L" + i).css('background-color', "#DCC9FF");
}

for (let i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
    $temp = splitString[i];
    if ($temp > "") {
        $("#I" + i).val($temp);
        setup_color(i);
    }
}
```